# What does <> next to extends class does in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

In facebooks flux-utils example, they do something like this:

```
import {ReduceStore} from 'flux/utils';

class CounterStore extends ReduceStore<number> {
  getInitialState(): number {
    return 0;
  }

  reduce(state: number, action: Object): number {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'increment':
        return state + 1;

      case 'square':
        return state * state;

      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what the `<number>` angle brackets next to `ReduceStore` does in JS?

I tried to look this up but don't really know what this es6 feature is called...

Thanks to anyone that helps!

Comment: Why you tag Java - "Java (not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript)..."

Comment: https://flow.org/

Comment: The code shown isn't (quite) JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't an ES6 feature, it's part of [Flow](https://flow.org/), a static typechecker for your ES6 code. It's sort of like TypeScript in the sense it adds new syntax though they have their substantial differences (TypeScript is full-fledged language). Flow uses Babel to transpile your type annotations to pure ES6.